# What's the color of Upsilon Scorpii?

Tags: star, amateur-observing

I was looking at the constellation Scorpius the other day, and noticed that the last star in the tail (the telson's tip) -- known as Upsilon Scorpii, υ Scorpii, or Lesath -- seemed yet more red than the "heart" of the scorpion -- Antares or Alpha Scorpii. Was it that I was drunk, or some kind of sky pollution? (Actually, a friend confirmed it was red, and she seemed sober than me.) Or is it, indeed, red? I couldn't find any information on-line. I saw [this database](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/icas/fchpix), but don't know how to find a star by its name, or if they have information about the color.

Comment: @RobJeffries The red color was confirmed by at least another person (see my edit). Is there any site like a on-line telescope?

Comment: Rodrigo, what you saw and what the star is are two different things. The star *is* blue/white. When you look at it through the atmosphere, especially low to the horizon, then it may *appear* to be something else. You asked a question - you have the answer.

Comment: @RobJeffries δ Sco, β Sco and π Sco were almost behind some not very close trees, so somewhat close to the horizon. Therefore υ Sco wasn't so low. It was the first time that I noticed it look SO red, and this called my attention. I would like if it could be confirmed by someone else (or at least discover why it appeared so red).

Comment: Actually it is *very* close to lambda Sco which is a brighter star. But just as blue/white.

Comment: @RobJeffries Yes, together they form the "telson" of the scorpion, also known as "Cat's Eyes". Both were clearly visible, but only Upsilon was red.

Comment: Then it is a mystery since Upsilon Sco is a blue, non-varying star...

Comment: The Sun is a yellow star but looks red near the horizon. No amount of second opinions will change the likelihood that the colour you saw is attributable to atmospheric effects.

Comment: @Chappo But the other stars in the constellation weren't red, even being lower on the horizon.

Comment: Then it is indeed a mystery! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what could cause [Upsilon Scorpii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsilon_Scorpii) to appear red as it is not noted as being a highly variable star. It's spectral type is B2, which implies it would be blue/white in colour. If you know the spectral type of a star, which many stellar databases will note, you can work out its colour from this.

Comment: The red color was confirmed by at least another person (see my edit). Is there any site like a on-line telescope? I got intrigued about this.

Comment: [Aladin Lite](http://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/AladinLite/?target=upsilon%20scorpii&fov=0.44&survey=P%2FDSS2%2Fcolor) shows Upsilon Scorpii as blue in the DSS2 survey.

Answer (score 2):

Upsilon Sco is a blue/white (B-V =-0.17) B2 IV star according to the [SIMBAD](http://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=Upsilon%20Sco&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit%20id) database entry.

As a slightly evolved B-type star it is unlikely to show any great variability and none has been recorded as far as I can see from a scan of the available references on the star. In fact it was included in a catalogue of the "least variable stars" by [Adelman (2001)](https://www.aanda.org/component/article?access=bibcode&bibcode=&bibcode=2001A%2526A...367..297AFUL), based on long duration monitoring by the Hipparcos satellite.

It might appear red if observed very low through a dusty atmosphere.